# How to use JSF 2 composite component "editableValueHolder" tag with a not fixed "name" property

Tags: jsf-2, composite

How to use JSF 2 composite component `editableValueHolder` tag with a not fixed `name` property. I need to accept converters in my new composite component. For that, I'm doing the following code:

#### outputText.xhtml

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="false" />
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="txtText"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText id="txtText" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

#### example.xhtml

```
<cv:outputText id="txtText" value="#{bean.description}" >
    <f:converter converterId="TestConverter" for="txtText"/>
</cv:outputText>
```

In this case, I'm needing to define the editableValueHolder's name attribute static and do the same with the "for" attribute in converter declaration. I need to know what was specified in editableValueHolder's name to copy it to "for" in f:converter tag.

I'd like to know if there is another way to do this, like passing a parameter for the editableValueHolder's name attribute.

Comment: Why you need a dynamic name for editableValueHoder?

Comment: Actually, I need a dynamic name for "f:converter's for" attribute. The user of my component should not know what ID he needs to put in "f:converter's for" attribute to get a working converter. Note that if the ID used in "converter's for" is different from the ID used in "editableValueHolder's name", the converter will not work.